# angular 2 webpack-dev-server , routing not working

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I install webpack , everything is fine , but Routing is not working anymore ,

```js
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'main' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'main', component: mainPage },
  { path: 'verification', component: Verification },
  { path: 'profile', component: Profile },
  { path: 'search', component: Search },
  { path: 'userProfile', component: UserProfile },
];
```

before i install webpack routing was working fine

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: already  found solution  i post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I Found my mistake , instead "start": "webpack-dev-server", in package.json i use , "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",